# How to send a link via MFMailComposer?

Tags: ios, swift, email

My **actual** problem is to send a link with a YouTube-Adress per email with Swift.

I use MFMailComposer and sure, it´s no problem to attach a file. But a link?

Is there any way to attach a **link** only, so the receiver can click the link that calls the YouTube-Page???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use HTML for that purpose:

```
// Add your body in a HTML format
let body = "<p>This is a test. Check out the link to youtube</p> <a href=\"http://www.youtube.com\">YouTube</a>"
// In your mail instance in setMessageBody, add your body and set isHTML to true
mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)
```

**Update**

If you don´t need a placeholder you could just add `http://...` URL in the email text as @rmaddy commented.

Comment: @rmaddy, if he want to add a placeholder then HTML is the only way or?

Comment: @user2893289: a placeholder is fine, but Thanks anywhere